# Is it possible to embed wps in my app

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to embed a wps functionality in a native iOS app? I would like to design a graphical interface from which to allow the user who has physical access to a router with a wps button to have the iPhone join that wifi network using wps. Any general advise where to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you get the needed low-level access to the wfi adapter, sorry .. or do you wanna do this on a jailbroken device/not for appstore

Comment: Nop, I wanted to do it legal...for appstore; I will take your answer for good if within a reasonable time no different information is provided; thanks by now